# Why shouldn't we use & in HashSet::insert?

Tags: rust

I am learning Rust after C++. Want to understand why shouldn't we use `&` in `HashSet::insert()` function?

We are using `&` in `HashSet::contains()` function because we don't want to own object
I would expect the same for the  `insert()`

I was reading documentation https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashSet.html#method.insert and understand signature of the method `pub fn insert(&mut self, value: T) -> bool`
Why don't we use `&value` ?

My code

```
use std::collections::HashSet;


fn main() {
    let mut hset = HashSet::new();
    let num = 111;

    hset.insert(num);
    if hset.contains(&num) {
        println!("Contains {}", num);
    }

    println!("{:?}", hset);
}
```

Comment: You want the HashSet to take ownership of the inserted value, so it persists as long as the HashSet does

Comment: Thank you, could you please elaborate?

Comment: *"I would expect the same for the `insert()`"* - would you mind elaborating why you would expect that?

Comment: The memory holding the value is freed when the variable it's bound to goes out of scope. So if you pass a reference to a hashmap the compiler would have to prove the thing you're taking a reference to lives longer than the hashmap, otherwise you could have a dangling pointer left in the map (a common source of bugs). Since that would be difficult or even impossible,  it makes more sense for the hashmap to take values that own their memory.

Answer (score 4):

Let me try to use a metaphor: your `HashSet`is a bag, and your `T` is the type of things you can put into that bag. You own the bag and are responsible to run my *requests*.

So now when I use `HashSet::contains()` I am holding an object, for example a red ball, and I ask you: *Is there a similar object in the bag?* Note that the ball is mine, but I let you borrow it so you can use it to compare to the objects inside the bag. When you are done you return the borrowed object and reply with "yes" or "no".

But when I use `HashSet::insert()` I give you the ball, and you insert that very same ball into the bag. If a similar object is already in the bag, then you trash the new ball (you do not want duplicated objects in your bag!) and reply "no". Else you insert the ball into the bag and reply "yes". Note that in either case now I do not have the ball any more.

So in the `contains()` case you pass a reference with `&` because you are borrowing the object to be used for a while. But with `insert()` you pass the object itself as an owned value so that the container is able to own it.

Answer (score 1):

In many cases you will want the HashSet to *own* the values it contains. In those cases you just want to pass the values directly, i.e. to *move* them, when calling [insert()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashSet.html#method.insert).

However, the above doesn't mean you can't store references to objects instead. If you call `hset.insert(&num)`, the compiler will infer the HashSet type as something like `HashSet<&i32>` (if `num`'s type is `ì32`).

You can test that with this code:

```
use std::collections::HashSet;

fn main() {
    let mut hset = HashSet::new();
    let num: i32 = 111;
    hset.insert(&num);
    hset.aaaaa();
}
```

the compiler will tell you this:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `aaaaa` found for struct `HashSet` in the    current scope
 --> src/main.rs:7:10
  |
7 |     hset.aaaaa();
  |          ^^^^^ method not found in `HashSet<&i32>`
```

BTW in the above example I explicitly set `num`'s type to be `ì32`. If we didn't specify that, the compiler's output might be a bit more generic in its message, but still specific enough: `HashSet<&{integer}>` (i.e., it can still infer you're trying to store a *reference* to some integer).

Note that for simple types like `i32` there's rarely a need to store references to such values, since making a copy of the value is usually a lot more efficient. If you wanted to store strings though, it depends. For short strings cloning those is usually a simple and fast enough approach. For longer string you might want to avoid cloning by using `HashSet<&str>` instead, but then you might need some extra consideration/work w.r.t. ownership and lifetimes.